# WinAPI using SetfilePointer to test EOF

Tags: c, winapi, file-io

Hi guys If I want to test EOF using

```
SetFilePointer(fi1, 0, NULL, FILE_CURRENT) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER
```

or ?

```
SetFilePointer(fi1, 1, NULL, FILE_CURRENT) != INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER
```

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/aa365541.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither really does the trick. The first won't detect EOF, and the second moves the file pointer which I guess is not what you want.

You should read the file pointer by calling `SetFilePointerEx` with a "move method" of `FILE_CURRENT` and a distance of zero. And compare that against the file size, obtained by calling `GetFileSizeEx`.

```
LARGE_INTEGER pos, size;
if (!SetFilePointerEx(hfile, 0, &pos, FILE_CURRENT))
    HandleError();
if (!GetFileSizeEx(hfile, &size))
    HandleError();
bool eof = (pos.QuadPart == size.QuadPart);
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the file pointer can be greater than the file size. For instance, SetFilePointer/Ex(>filesize) followed by SetEndOfFile() is commonly used for expanding or pre-allocating files. So you should use `>=` instead of `==` in the comparison.